# A QGraphicsLineItem is disappearing when both endpoints are outside of the view. How can I stop that from happening?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have a very long QGraphicsLineItem in a QGraphicsScene, and when both endpoints of the line are outside of the QGraphicsView, the line is no longer drawn, even though it passes through the view.  I imagine Qt just examines the endpoints when determining if a line is inside a view, but that method has a problem if the line passes all the way from one side of a view to the other.  Is there a way I can correct this?

Comment: Which version of the Qt do you use?

Comment: I have tried that with the Qt 5.4.0 and it works well: the QGraphicsLineItem  is visible even if it's endpoints are off the view.

Comment: I'm actually using PyQt, and it is version 4.8.7

Comment: I have a Qt 4.7 and have not seen this behavior. Your issue must be something else. Possibly the points are not where you think they are.